# Objective-C NSButton Toggle

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton

I have search and can't find any information so I would like some help here. I am new to Xcode and objective c. I have 10 NSButtons set in Interface Builder to be Push On Push Off type. I am trying to figure out how when one of the buttons is clicked and highlighted, how do I unhightlight the other nine. I am use to Java, in java you can just make an if statement to turn off the highlight of the buttons not clicked. In IB I don't see how to send a message to the other buttons because I don't know their "names" or addresses. Can you please help me figure this out, explain it or send me to a link or video. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've used in the past.

Create an NSArray with all your buttons in it, something like:

```
NSArray* buttons = @[button1, button2, button3, button4];
```

Then create a method like this.

```
- (void) toggleButtons: (id) sender {
    for (Button *item in buttons) {
        if (item == sender) {
            item.selected = !item.selected;
        } else {
            item.button.selected = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Now call it from each of your button handlers:

```
- (IBAction) handleButton1:(id) sender {
    [self toggleButtons:sender];
    <...rest of your code...>
}
```